# how can I populate a listView from an external database (xampp) into a fragment?

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, android-fragments

I have an android app with navigation drawer and fragments. I am trying to populate a listView with data from a database in mySql (xampp). To retrive the data from the database i use an php script.

The fragment:

```
public class CommunityFragment extends ListFragment {
// Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url_all_products = "http://127.0.0.1/conectareBD/afiseaza_date_clienti_fizici.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_CLIENTI = "clienti";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "ID_Client";
    private static final String TAG_NUME = "Nume";
    private static final String TAG_PRENUME = "Prenume";
    private static final String TAG_ADRESA="Adresa";
    private static final String TAG_TELEFON="Telefon";
    private static final String TAG_EMAIL="Email";
    private static final String TAG_TIP_CLIENT="TipClient";
    private static final String TAG_CREATE_AT="CreatAT";


    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray clienti = null;

    EditText inputSearch;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



public CommunityFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_community, container, false);
 // Hashmap for ListView
    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    //ListView lv = getListView();
    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);




    return rootView;
}


/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Toti clientii: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                clienti = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTI);
                int nr=clienti.length();
                Log.d("lungime ",nr+" ");

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < clienti.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = clienti.getJSONObject(i);
                    Log.d("obiect ",i+" " +c.toString());
                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = String.valueOf(i); //c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String nume = c.getString(TAG_NUME);
                    String prenume = c.getString(TAG_PRENUME);
                    String adresa=c.getString(TAG_ADRESA);
                    String email=c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
                    String telefon=c.getString(TAG_TELEFON);
                    String createAT=c.getString(TAG_CREATE_AT);

                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_NUME, nume);
                    map.put(TAG_PRENUME, prenume);
                    map.put(TAG_ADRESA, adresa);
                    map.put(TAG_TELEFON, telefon);


                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    productsList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                //open a new fragment

                Fragment fragment = new PhotosFragment();
                 FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction();
                    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
                            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), productsList,
                        R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                TAG_NUME,TAG_PRENUME},
                        new int[] { R.id.pid, R.id.name,R.id.prenume });
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);






            }
        });

    }




}
```

I have the following errors:

```
  04-20 17:06:09.555: W/System.err(689):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.socket(BlockGuardOs.java:181)
04-20 17:06:09.635: W/System.err(689):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.socket(IoBridge.java:568)
04-20 17:06:09.665: W/System.err(689):  ... 21 more
04-20 17:06:09.665: E/Buffer Error(689): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 17:06:09.684: E/JSON Parser(689): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
04-20 17:06:09.814: W/dalvikvm(689): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
04-20 17:06:09.834: I/Choreographer(689): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.CommunityFragment$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(CommunityFragment.java:173)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.CommunityFragment$LoadAllProducts.doInBackground(CommunityFragment.java:1)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
04-20 17:06:09.994: E/AndroidRuntime(689):  ... 5 more
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Where it occurred.. on emulator or device ?

Comment: The errors occured on emulator

Answer (score 0):

Use `10.0.2.2` to access the `localhost` of host computer because on emulator, `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address of emulator itself as defined in [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking):

```
String url_all_products = "http://10.0.2.2/conectareBD/afiseaza_date_clienti_fizici.php";
```

Comment: I have the same errors with 10.0.2.2.Actually, in my code i use the IP adress instead  127.0.0.1...

Comment: 1. Instead of JSONParser's _makeHttpRequest()_ first try to get the data with _HttpURLConnection_ class to check whether you are able to connect to that IP address or not 2. Try to connect to some other website like google.com by using _HttpURLConnection_ class 3. Ensure that you send correct parameters in HTTP request